# how to pass special characters like & + % in jsp in URL

Tags: java, xml, jsp

I am new to jsp.
I am taking user input(name) in a textfields. This input is saved in xml file.
I am using name attribute as a parameter and sending this parameter to another jsp file so that user can add child nodes to the given parameter.

Everything is working perfect except for `& + %`. I am converting parameter to `httpparam` so `& value is %26 + value is %2B and % value is %25`. `/ value is %2F` all others are working fine.
I am having no trouble with other special characters but as I include & + % it is giving me empty value and not null in other jsp hidden fields.and thats why I am not getting any value from String name = request.getParameter("name");this statement.
Even my URL looks like jsp?name=%25 for % parameter. and ...jsp?name=%26 for & parameter 
and ...jsp?name=%2B for + as a parameter
My xml file has ISO-8859-1 encoding   
problem2) if I send parameter as  (which is name given by user) its also empty and not null but alone < or > or >< or <> are working fine
and I can not restrict entering special characters as it is requirement

could any one help me 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please pay more attention on formatting your question, separating code sections, grammar, etc. to make it more readable and easier for others to answer.

Comment: ?param1=%2B&param2=%2B You don't want to encode the & between parameters, only the ampersand inside a parameter value. Is that the question?

Answer (score 0):

Ordinarily web browsers automatically perform URL encoding on form fields, however you can perform encoding and decoding yourself using the appropriate classes.  You might want to check out:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

and

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html